# Elasticsearch boost and order alphabetically

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use sort and order a field alphabetically and then also use a script to boost certain documents using the same field all other documents order should be preserved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , its possible.
Make sure your script returns 0 for all the fields it dont have a say about.

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": "doc['age'].value ",
        "params": {
          "factor": 1.1
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As we have given sum , the sum of the field value and the script would be taken as score.

Comment: I'm getting the following exception: lassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]; }] my field is a string field so I'm not sure how it can return an integer.

Comment: Seems field_value_factor can only work on number , i have modified my answer to use sort.